# variable binding inside an object

Tags: javascript

in this code below:

```
var a = 1;
var boat = { a:2, 
             innerBoat: {a:3, 
                        print(){console.log(a);},
                        },
            }; 
boat.innerBoat.print();  //output: 1
```

i don't understand why console.log(a); in print method returns the value 1.

Also, does the curly braces {} of the object referenced by boat creates a new private execution context in the stack at runtime ? (I know that only function calls create a new private execution context at runtime, but object creation confuses me, because they are originally a constructor call:

```
var boat = new Object();
```

Comment: You declared global variable a and this is returned in console.log. Use boat.a and return 2, use boat.innerBoat.a and return 3, use this.a and return 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i don't understand why console.log(a); in print method returns the value 1.

It logs the value of the **variable** `a`.

The **properties** of the various objects around it which also have the name `a` are not variables. They can only be referenced as properties of an object.

```js
const a = 1;
const object = {
    a: 2
};

console.log(a);
console.log(object.a)
```

---

See also [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for how to access the property of an object that the method you are calling is attached to.

---

> Also, does the curly braces {} of the object referenced by boat creates a new private execution context in the stack at runtime ?

No.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, an `object` really is nothing more than a collection of data, like a dictionary in many other languages.

`var boat = new Object();` just creates an empty object, as if you did `var boat = {};`

If you're looking for something more like , you may try using ES6 classes

```js
var a = 0
class Boat {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 1;
  }
  print() {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
}
var boat = new Boat()
boat.print();  //output: 2
```